# Where can I find Ubuntu .img file to use on Android?

Tags: system-installation

I am looking for a Ubuntu .img file that I can copy to an SD card and use in Android Key.  .iso files, I can find easily, but not .img files.

Comment: Are you trying to Install Ubuntu onto your Android device?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you can just rename the `.iso` to `.img`.

Otherwise open a burning program like Brasero and create it from the `.iso`. Or any other burning programs (to name a few: k3b, gnomebaker, Nero).